# Car won't start problem

Tags: engine, starting, nissan, starter

I have a problem with my car it won’t start. Just a little background on my car, I have a 2008 Nissan Versa and I have a cold air intake installed in my car with a hydro shield covering the air filter and the area is fully cover by fender lining sides and bottom.

Prior to the car not starting I drove in the rain to get gas from Valero (I usually go to Arco) to work and parked my car outside for 6 hours and started the car with no problems and drove home. The next day I reparked my car in the garage again no problems except I smelled gasoline when i stepped out of the car and left the car in my garage for a whole day. The following afternoon I turned on my car and it cranked and sounds like a whirring sound but car won’t start.

I had it towed to the dealership and they did a engine diagnosis and couldn’t find anything wrong but took off the starter to give to the shop to have it tested. He also mentioned that there could be water in the engine because I do have a cold air intake, but I don’t believe it could be hydrolock because I didn’t drive through a flood or deep puddles. What are your thoughts on why my car won’t start? Thank you for reading!

Comment: If the engine is cranking but not starting, it's not hydrolocked.

Comment: Thank you for responding. The nissan service technician told me that an engine that cranks but won't start could be hydrolock, but hopefully you are right and I believe it isn't hydrolock also. I'm thinking it might be something with the gas I put in 2 days before my car stopped starting but I've been told the gas shouldn't matter.

Comment: Then you need to go see a different tech, or he didn't explain it very well. The main part of hyrdolocked is "locked". As you know, liquid will not compress. To hydrolock, an engine has to suck in water during the intake phase, then as the intake valve closes and the piston comes up to compress, it gets to a point and stops. At this point, the engine will not rotate in the direction it normally runs (you can back it off). At this point, valves usually get bent and all kinds of ugliness. If it's hydrolocked, it WILL NOT turn over.

Comment: So the service tech called me and told me that the car starts just fine which is really weird. They have no explanation why it wouldn't start and start again couple days later.

Comment: You should explain what is Valero and Arco.

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical case in the computer industry of *fixed while troubleshooting*. Not much else to be said.